# Configuring bind9 to resolve all queries to the same IP

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I am trying to configure a DNS server on Ubuntu 13.10, so that any DNS query inside our local network would be resolved to `192.168.0.101`.

I have tried different things, followed a few tutorial, but didn't get any result. Mostly I am a bit overwhelmed by all these new concepts, as I have never done this kind of things before.

I have changed `/etc/resolv.conf` to use `127.0.0.1` as DNS server, just for testing, and tried the following query : `dig blabla.com`, which gave me the answer `status: SERVFAIL`

Here is my current *bind* configuration :

In `named.conf.options` (I simply added `recursion yes`)

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };

        recursion yes;
};
```

In `named.conf.local`

```
zone "." {
 type master;
 file "/etc/bind/zones/root.db";
 };
```

In `/etc/bind/zones/root.db`

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 1D
@    IN     SOA  @ none. ( 0 1D 1H 1W 3H );
     IN     NS   @
*    IN     A    192.168.0.101
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think bind can easily do this, and for a very good reason: this is a horribly broken thing to do and you should find a better way of achieving what you want. I'm guessing you want a transparent proxy, so set up a transparent proxy, don't fuck up DNS.

But if you really want to break DNS for your users, dnsmasq actually allows you to do this: `dnsmasq --address=/#/1.2.3.4`

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answer that points out that doing this kind of thing seems like a bad idea.

However, I would think that the reason for your `SERVFAIL` responses is simply that the zone file for your `.` zone (as posted in the question) is invalid.

An error that I immediately see is that the `NS` record refers to the name `.` but `.` has no `A` or `AAAA` records.

Your logs will have this error in it (and possibly additional errors that I did not immediately spot).

In addition to reading logs, `named-checkconf` (validates configuration) and `named-checkzone` (validates zone data) are also invaluable tools to have as part of your workflow when working with bind.

I find `named-checkconf -zj` to be particularly useful for getting an overview of both configuration and zone data.